# Laravel Why my image post function doesn't work correctly?

Tags: php, html, laravel

## Basic Information

I'm developing a simple Web Application using Laravel6.0.

I made an image post function but it doesn't work correctly.

There are no error messages.

## Problem

I can't post an Image.

Nothing changed.

It just transit to same page.

`create2.blade.php` is form to post the image and i want to view this image on `index2.blade.php`

## Codes

### routes/web.php

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('login');

Route::group(['middleweare' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'StoriesController@index');
    Route::post('/', 'StoriesController@index');
    Route::post('/stories/create', 'StoriesController@upload');
    Route::get('/stories/create', 'StoriesController@add');
    Route::post('/stories/create', 'StoriesController@add');
});

Route::group(['middleweare' => 'auth','name'=>'profile'], function () {
    Route::get('/profile/edit', 'ProfileController@edit');
    Route::get('/profile/create', 'ProfileController@add');
    Route::post('/profile/create', 'ProfileController@add');
    Route::post('/profile/create', 'ProfileController@store');
    Route::post('/profile/create', 'ProfileController@upload');
});

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Auth::routes();
```

### app/Http/Controllers/StoriesController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Story;
use Auth;
use App\Posts;
use App\History;
use App\Attachment;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Storage;

class StoriesController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct()
    {
      $this->middleware('auth');
    }

  public function index(Request $request)
      {
        $images = Attachment::all();

        return view('stories.index2', compact('images'));
      }

  public function add()
    {
      return view('stories.create2');
    }


  public function store(Request $request)
  {

    $d = new \DateTime();
    $d->setTimeZone(new \DateTimeZone('Asia/Tokyo'));
    $dir = $d->format('Y/m');
    $path = sprintf('public/images/%s', $dir);


    $data = $request->except('_token');

    foreach ($data['images'] as $k => $v) {

      $filename = '';


      $attachments = Attachment::take(1)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

      foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

        $filename = $attachment->id + 1 . '_' . $v->getClientOriginalName();
      }
      unset($attachment);

      if ($filename == false) {
        $filename = 1 . '_' . $v->getClientOriginalName();
      }

      $v->storeAs($path, $filename);

      $attachment_data = [
        'path' => sprintf('images/%s/', $dir),
        'name' => $filename
      ];

      $a = new Attachment();
      $a->fill($attachment_data)->save();
    }

    unset($k, $v);

    return redirect('/');
  }


  public function upload(Request $request)
    {
      dd($request->all());
      $this->validate($request, [
        'file' => [
          'required',
          'file',
          'image',
          'mimes:jpeg,png',
        ]
      ]);

      if ($request->file('file')->isValid([])) {
        $path = $request->file->store('public');
        return view('stories.index2')->with('filename', basename($path));
      } else {
        return redirect('/')
          ->back()
          ->withInput()
          ->withErrors();
      }
    }
}
```

### resources/views/stories/create2.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.front2')
@section('title','StoryCreate')

@section('content')
<link href="{{ asset('/css/main22.css' )}}" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="poststory">
    <h1>Post Story</h1>
</div>
@if ($errors->any())
<ul>
    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
@endif
<form action="{{ url('/') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="form">
        <label for="photo" class="file">Choose Image or Video</label>
        <div class="post">
            <input type="file" class="here" name="images[]">

        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    </div>

    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="post">
        <div class="btn postbtn">
            <input type="submit" value="post" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@endsection
```

### resources/views/stories/index2.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.front2')
@section('title','mainpage')

@section('content')
<div class="profile">

    <div class="profileimg">
        @foreach ($images as $image)
        <img src="/storage/{{ $image->path . $image->name }}" style="height: 210px; width: 210px; border-radius: 50%;">
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <div class="name">
        @guest
        <a class="nav-link2" href="{{ route('register')}}">{{ __('Create Accout!')}}</a>
        @else
        <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link2" href="#" role="button">
            {{Auth::user()->name}}<span class="caret"></span></a>



        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
            @csrf
        </form>
    </div>
    @endguest


    <div class="aboutme">
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
        You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!You can write your profile here!
    </div>

</div>

<div class="new">

    <div class="newtitle">
        <h1>New</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container1">

        @foreach ($images as $image)
        <img src="/storage/{{ $image->path . $image->name }}" class="images" style="height: 150px; width: 150px; border-radius: 50%;">
        @endforeach
        <div class="more">
            more...
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="stories">

    <div class="titlestories">
        <h1>Stories</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container2">

        <div class="titleclose">
            <h2>#CloseFriends</h2>
        </div>

        @foreach ($images as $image)
        <img src="/storage/{{ $image->path . $image->name }}" class="images" style="height: 150px; width: 150px; border-radius: 50%;">
        @endforeach

        <div class="titlefollow">
            <h2>#Follows</h2>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>

{{ csrf_field() }}
@endsection
```

sorry for my terrible English but, i need help.

Waiting for your comments and Answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two definitions for `POST /stories/create` in your routes file.

```
   Route::post('/stories/create', 'StoriesController@upload');
   ...
   Route::post('/stories/create', 'StoriesController@add');
```

The last one processed will be receiving the requests to this route. You should be able to verify this on the command line by running `php artisan route:list` and looking and which routes are available and which controllers they are mapped to. In this case, you are likely hitting the add method instead of the upload method.

As an immediate fix, remove the second definition from routes file, rerun `php artisan route:list` to look for the change, and see if the webpage behaves differently.

It looks like you will face a similar problem with:

```
  Route::post('/profile/create', 'ProfileController@add');
  Route::post('/profile/create', 'ProfileController@store');
  Route::post('/profile/create', 'ProfileController@upload');
```

Resourceful routing can help standardize routing and save a lot of headaches and confusion like this. https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers

In particular, if you define your routes as described at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes, you can use `php artisan route:list` to verify which methods each route is mapped to, and then update your controllers to match.

```
Route::resource('stories', 'StoriesController')->only([
    'index', 
    'create', 
    'store',
]);
```

Comment: I removed the second definition `Route::post('/stories/create', 'StoriesController@add');` and I update the routing `Route::post('/','StoriesController@store');` then my problem has solved! thank you and i appreciate for the answers.